# Record and play back mouse+keyboard

Tags: keyboard, software-recommendation, mouse

Can anyone suggest a program I can use as a keyboard and mouse recorder?

I tried CNee/EZ macro but it is not working.

[image]

Comment: The offering of easy to use keyboard automation tools in linux is very scarce. Autokey was quite good but it is not maintained and does not work anymore. With some own scripting, you can achieve something with utilities like xdotools end xclip. However, make sure you use X and not Wayland, because xdotool, and maybe also xclip,  does not work on wayland